# Dúvida com validação CPF

Tags: android

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer uma validação no cpf e estou encontrando problemas... 
Quando digito qualquer número que não se encontra no if, ele insere  no banco normalmente, 
mas quando eu digito números de dentro do if eu gostaria que ele mostrasse a mensagem de cpf inválido e não jogasse para  banco,
mas o máximo que eu consegui foi inserir "CPF INVÁLIDO!!!" no banco... Se alguém puder me ajudar... estou mandando três print com as classes Conexao, Socio e validarCpf.
Se alguém puder me ajudar, serei muito grato... Obrigado!!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está a validação? Poste o código puro (texto) ao invés de imagem.

Comment: Não abra perguntas a torto e a direito iguais. Edite as suas perguntas e altere o que pretender. Sabe como editar? É só clicar no botão logo a esquerda por cima destes comentários.

Comment: Outra coisa, foto de "código" é o cúmulo... não concorda? Não leve a mal o comentário, por favor.