# Erro na validação do CPF

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer uma validação no CPF e estou encontrando problemas.
Quando digito qualquer número que não se encontra no `if`, ele insere  no banco normalmente, 
mas quando eu digito números de dentro do `if` eu gostaria que ele mostrasse a mensagem de cpf inválido e não jogasse para  banco,
mas o máximo que eu consegui foi inserir "CPF INVÁLIDO!!!" no banco... Se alguém puder me ajudar. estou mandando três classes `Conexao`, `Socio` e `validarCpf`.

Classe `Conexao`
:

```
public void CadastrarUsuario() {
    conectarBanco();

    CpfValidacao ver2 = new CpfValidacao();

    try {
        Socio cadastrarNovoSocio = new Socio();
        CpfValidacao ver = new CpfValidacao();

        String sql = ("insert into cadastrousuario values('"
                + cadastrarNovoSocio.getNome() + "','"
                + cadastrarNovoSocio.getEmail() + "','"
                + cadastrarNovoSocio.getDdd() + "','"
                + cadastrarNovoSocio.getTelefoneUsuario() + "','"
                + ver.getValidaCpf()+"')");

        stm.executeUpdate(sql);
        con.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro: " + e);

    }
}
```

---

Classe Socio

```
public String getCpf() {
    System.out.println("Informe o CPF: ");
    cpf = scan.nextLine();
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}
```

---

Classe CpfValidacao

```
public class CpfValidacao {
    private String validaCpf;

    public void fecharConexao(){
        Conexao teste = new Conexao();
        teste.desconectarBanco();
    }
    public String getValidaCpf() {
        Socio validar = new Socio();
        validaCpf = validar.getCpf();

        if (validaCpf.equals("11111111111") || validaCpf.equals("22222222222")
                || validaCpf.equals("33333333333") || validaCpf.equals("44444444444")
                || validaCpf.equals("55555555555") ||validaCpf.equals("66666666666")
                || validaCpf.equals("77777777777") ||validaCpf.equals("88888888888")
                || validaCpf.equals("99999999999") ||validaCpf.length() != 11) {

            fecharConexao();
            return "CPF INVÁLIDO!!!";
        }
        return validaCpf;
    }
    public void fecharConexao(String validaCpf) {
        this.validaCpf = validaCpf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta pergunta está duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58349/d%C3%BAvida-com-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-cpf (e esta parece que está melhor formatada).

Comment: Esse método validaCpf não pega casos como 12345678910! De uma olhada aqui : http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-851371-Validacao-de-CPF.html

Answer (score 1):

Você não está inserindo o retorno do método direto em seu banco de dados não importa o que ele retornar, valide o cpf antes de dar um insert na tabela.

e uma observação voce poderia substituir todo esse `if`

```
    if (validaCpf.equals("11111111111") || validaCpf.equals("22222222222")
            || validaCpf.equals("33333333333") || validaCpf.equals("44444444444")
            || validaCpf.equals("55555555555") ||validaCpf.equals("66666666666")
            || validaCpf.equals("77777777777") ||validaCpf.equals("88888888888")
            || validaCpf.equals("99999999999") ||validaCpf.length() != 11) {

        fecharConexao();
        return "CPF INVÁLIDO!!!";
    }
```

por uma **expressão regular**:

```
    if (!validaCpf.matches("\\d{11,11}")) {
       fecharConexao();
        return "CPF INVÁLIDO!!!";
      }
```